# MKMapView not getting lat long value from var

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have latiude long values coming from json which are stored in NSString var.

```
NSString*lat=latitude;
NSString*longi=longitude;
mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: lat, longitude: longi};

MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

[mapView setRegion:region];
```

It's giving an error on CLLocationCoordinate2D unrecognized selector sent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `lat` and `longi` are string values. Convert them to `doubleValue`. Try this.

```
double _lat = [lat doubleValue];
double _lng = [longi doubleValue];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){_lat, _lng};
MKCoordinateSpan span = (MKCoordinateSpan){0.2, 0.2};
MKCoordinateRegion region = (MKCoordinateRegion){coord, span};
```

Comment: `lat` and `longi` are strings?

Comment: This should work. In which line app crashes? See my edited answer.